# How does lifelink affect indestructible creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My 4/4 lifelink creature is blocked by his 1/1 indestructible creature.
How much life do I gain, if any?

Answer (score 9):

**You will gain 4 life.**

Lifelink and indestructible have no special interactions with each other. Your 4/4 will deal 4 damage to the 1/1, and you will gain 4 life. This is the same as if your 4/4 had dealt damage to any other creature. It doesn't matter how much toughness the defending creature has, or whether it will eventually die.

> **510.1a** Each attacking creature and each blocking creature assigns combat damage equal to its power. Creatures that would assign 0 or less damage this way don’t assign combat damage at all.

Comment: @Tony: If you believe your question has been sufficiently answered, please accept one of the answers to remove it from the unanswered queue. You should also [comment only to add informational value](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) to the post.

Comment: The rules definition of indestructible would be helpful here; as the confusion seems to come from not being sure if indestructible creatures are dealt damage.

Comment: @GendoIkari I considered it originally, but ultimately decided not to include the rules quote because it doesn't make a difference whether the creature has indestructible or not (just as it doesn't matter if the creature ultimately lives or dies). I feel the extra text will just add to that confusion. (Plus the rules text is basically just "This creature doesn't die to lethal damage.")